# Display arrow-boxes in repeater control in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

![enter image description here][1]

Hi,

I want to display data in repeater control like in below images. I have attached outuput of screen shot. I have  searched a lot of things in internet but didnt find exactly way to develope.
Could anyone please how to implement this task. The data comes from database and bind with repeater contol and display with boxes and arrrow between them. How  to draw arrow-boxes and rectagnle in repeater control and how to get xy position of each row and each recrod cell data at run time.

![enter image description here][2]

Comment: I cannot see the image, but in repeater you don't need to have row xy. Please add image and clarify more

Comment: I am geting below error while uploading images. How to resolve it.

Comment: Error:-
×

You need at least 10 reputation to post images.

Comment: If possible Could you please send your email id i will send image

Comment: Why do you want xy position of each row?

Comment: Could you please put the repeater code?

Comment: I want display data in below format

Comment: Below data come from database, want to display in page, how to show which control is feasible for that


Output-----

Header Table         DVD                 CD            Seller
 row                 Rani--------------> Kiran---------> India
 row                 Kiran-------------> Raja----------> china

Comment: Below data come from database, want to display in page, how to show which control is feasible for that


Output-----

Header Table         DVD                 CD            Seller
 row 1                Rani--------------> Kiran---------> India
 row 2                Kiran-------------> Raja----------> china

Comment: There is an [edit] link under your question that let you update your post. Also take the [tour] and visit the [help] to improve the quality of your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like that

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <div>
            <div>DVD</div>
            <div>
                <img src="~/imagebox.jpg" /></div>
            <div>CD</div>
            <div>
                <img src="~/imagebox.jpg" /></div>
            <div>Seller</div>
        </div>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div id='row<%# Container.ItemIndex%>'>
            <div><%#Eval("DVD") %></div>
            <div>
                <img src="~/imagebox.jpg" /></div>
            <div><%#Eval("CD") %></div>
            <div>
                <img src="~/imagebox.jpg" /></div>
            <div><%#Eval("Seller") %></div>
        </div>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

By using this code you always have your image between different divs. you just need to consider that you have to add a class with defined width for divs to make them align in columns.

Comment: thanks for giving soultions but in this situation the arrow marks is comletely mapping to next column with same row. What about if row1 DVD data mapping to row2 Seller? how to display arrow marks from row1 DVD data to row2 Seller data. here parrent child relation data.

Comment: http://www.headjump.de/article/arrows-and-boxes,     http://scholar.lib.vt.edu/ejournals/JTE/v24n1/williams.html   Please check this url I want to display data look like this in rectangle box with arrow between two to three boxes in tabular format

Comment: https://www.google.fi/search?q=arrows+between+nodes&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=QPDxU9zaFYqi0QWLiIHYCQ&sqi=2&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&biw=1366&bih=651#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=IySJxMGdrhLEbM%253A%3BCHTJJOrejAemiM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Feloquentjavascript.net%252Fimg%252Fhtml-tree.svg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Feloquentjavascript.net%252F13_dom.html%3B439%3B259

Comment: i have uploaded images which is my goal of project

Comment: If you didn't have Germany between Paris and UK it would be possible to do some parts using Repeater and some jobs using JavaScript but in current case I am pretty sure you cannot use Repeater. the easiest way probably would be finding some component to support it.

Comment: Oh! these data is dynamaically, parrent-child relationship, so all data should display with boxes and arrowmarks. I need some other component, could you please tell me,  is it sure i cannnot use of Gridview, repeter control.

Comment: Can we get xy position of these data which is in repeater or grideveiw. If got xy position then we can make arrow marks by using java script or css or code behind logic graphic like pen

Comment: Please see the updated code. when you have the id as index using jquery or java script you can get each row x and y

Comment: I saw the code but can get xy position of each data in code behind in Repeater1_ItemDataBound() at run time.

Comment: No You cannot get it in item databound

Comment: then how can get xy position wihtout using User

Comment: What you mean using User?

Comment: First bind the data to repeater, then get xy position of each row and coluarrow marks to map between cell data,

Comment: No I believe the only way is making that with index id after that do everything using javascript.

Comment: 1st Step :- To bind data to repeater control 2nd Step:- to get xy position of each row and coloumn of data which is in repeater 3rd Step:- Create arrow marks by using java script or jquery or css or graphich design in code behind 4th Step:- draw arrow marks with appropitate position of xy from source data to destination data Question.- Now my question about 2nd step, how to get xy position of row and coloumn in code behind before complete the page unload event.

Comment: You should not get it in code behind. after binding your code is like below:<div id='id1"><div>DVD</div></div> in jquery you should say: $("#id1).nth-child(1).left() hopefully I am correct but first make sure the jquery code is correct